# Is there a way to rebind "C-h" key in current buffer?

Tags: emacs

I have this in my init.el:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'backward-delete-char)
```

Matlab mode resets my global setting back to "help", and I can't get to use "local-set-key" in the buffer - it doesn't end key sequence when I press C-h, waiting to input of the next character (`C-h-`).

Is there a way to interactively fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy would be to add a hook for your matlab mode:

```
(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'backward-delete-char)))
```

As for interactively fixing it, I'm not aware of anyway to interactively give C-h as input to `local-set-key`...